# Mount EFI system partition at directory

Tags: windows, mount

I already know that `mountvol <Drive Letter>: /S` will mount the computer's EFI system partition—how it knows which one is the one that was used to boot the computer, I have no idea—at `<Drive Letter>:`. But how do I mount it at a directory such as `C:\ESP`?

Through `mountvol <path> <VolumeName>`, I have already configured my laptop's recovery and restore partitions to be mounted at my preferred paths, but I can't do this with the EFI system partition because I don't know what it's volume GUID is.

Answer (score 3):

In an elevated command prompt run the command `mountvol`

This will, after initial help, list all volumes.

[image]

Look for GUIDs with `NO MOUNT POINTS`

Run `start \\?\Volume{......<GUID>................}\`

and confirm that it opens EFI partition. That's the correct GUID.

[image]

Now once you found GUID of EFI, run the command

```
mountvol c:\esp\ \\?\Volume{....<GUID>.......}\
```

[image]

EFI partition is now mounted at `c:\esp`.

This will retain the mount point even after reboot.

[image]

To unmount, run the command

```
mountvol  "c:\esp" /D
```

Tested in Windows 10 VM. Check if this works on a real system.

However I suggest not to keep the EFI partition permanently mounted like this. Just mount it to a Drive Letter temporarily and release it after work is done to be on safer side.

Comment: Well, none of this works. First, trying to run `start \\?\Volume{<UUID>}\` returned `The system cannot execute the specified program.`. Second, trying to click on the folder in File Explorer that the only volume with `NO MOUNT POINTS` was mounted at using `mountvol <PATH> \\?\Volume{<UUID>}\ ` resulted in a dialog box saying `The volume mounted on folder <PATH> is not formatted.`, so that can't be the ESP.

Comment: Are you doing it in PowerShell or usual Command Prompt (cmd)? What version of Windows?

Comment: It's Windows 8 and I'm using Command Prompt.